# Merge sort for python

Tags: python, merge, mergesort

Here are my `merge` and `mergeSort` functions. `merge` merges two separate arrays and `mergesSort` sorts and merges them with recursion:

```
def merge(arrL, arrR):
    arrNew = []
    d = len(arrL) + len(arrR)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range (0, d-1):
        if (arrL[i] < arrR[j]) :
            arrNew.append(arrL[i]) # appends to the end of the array
            i = i + 1
        else:
            arrNew.append(arrR[j])
            j = j + 1
    return arrNew

def mergeSort(arr, m, n):
    if (n - m == 1):
        return arr[m]
    else:
        p = (m + n) // 2
        arrL = mergeSort(arr, m, p)
        arrR = mergeSort(arr, p, n)
        arrNew = merge(arrL, arrR)
        return arrNew
```

I am getting an error from lines 32, 33 and 13:

```
d = len(arrL) + len(arrR)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What is causing this error? merge is taking two arrays as inputs.

Comment: can you please accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing this error? `merge` is taking two arrays as inputs.

Except when it doesn't.

```
if(n-m == 1):
  return arr[m]
```

This output of `mergeSort` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's this line

```
if(n-m == 1):
    return arr[m]
```

which presumably is returning the content `arr[m]` of the array and not an array itself.

Since your code sorts arrays, when this naked element gets recursed on, it will generate the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- in `mergeSort`, you should return `arr` instead of `arr[m]` when the length of the array is less than 2. The test `if (n - m == 1)` does not allow for empty arrays:

  ```
    if (n - m < 2):
        return arr
  ```
- in `merge`, the main loop should run `d` times, ie: instead of `for k in range (0, d-1):` you should write:

  ```
    for k in range (d):
  ```
- the test in the merge loop should also check if the index value in still in range. If the second slice is exhausted, the element `arrL[i]` should be selected:

  ```
    for k in range (d):
        if i < len(arrL) and (j >= len(arrR) or arrL[i] < arrR[j]):
            arrNew.append(arrL[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            arrNew.append(arrR[j])
            j = j + 1
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
def merge(arrL, arrR):
    arrNew = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(len(arrL) + len(arrR)):
        if i < len(arrL) and (j >= len(arrR) or arrL[i] < arrR[j]):
            arrNew.append(arrL[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            arrNew.append(arrR[j])
            j = j + 1
    return arrNew

def mergeSort(arr, m, n):
    if (n - m < 2):
        return arr
    else:
        p = (m + n) // 2
        arrL = mergeSort(arr, m, p)
        arrR = mergeSort(arr, p, n)
        return merge(arrL, arrR)
```